# what is the xcode 4 template macro processor?

Tags: xcode4

xcode 4 templates are gross, and one of the problems I had when building mine was the macro expansion. ___VARIABLE_name:identifier  would replace the leading character with an underscore if that character was numeric.  I eventually figured out that the :identifier was modifying the expansion to make it a legal identifier.  Great.

I would like to know what macro language that looks like, if any, so i can find other available tricks when building out templates.

thanks.